# Struct containing unusual templated function in C++ code

Tags: visual-c++, com, iunknown

In the following C++ code (from a Microsoft COM header file), what is the part that starts with `template<class Q>...`?

I am thoroughly confused for other reasons as well, as although a `struct` is in use, it has class-like elements; for example, the `public` keyword.

```
extern "C++" {
    struct IUnknown {
    public:
        virtual HRESULT WINAPI QueryInterface(REFIID riid,void **ppvObject) = 0;
        virtual ULONG WINAPI AddRef(void) = 0;
        virtual ULONG WINAPI Release(void) = 0;
        template<class Q> HRESULT WINAPI QueryInterface(Q **pp) { return QueryInterface(__uuidof(*pp),(void **)pp); }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that starts with `template<class Q> HRESULT WINAPI QueryInterface` is a template member function. In other words, it's a function template that's a member of a class (or struct, in this case).

Being a template means you can pass any interface type as its parameter, and the compiler will generate a function to query an object for an interface of that type:

```
IFoo *x;
IBar *y;

if (foo.QueryInterface(&x) != S_OK) {
    // use x->whatever to invoke members of IFoo
}

if (foo.QueryInterface(&y) != S_OK) {
    // use y->whatever to invoke members of IBar
}
```

Since it's a function template, the compiler deduces the type for `Q` from the type of the parameter you pass so when you pass an `IFoo **`, `Q` has the type `IFoo`, and when you pass an `IBar **`, `Q` has the type `IBar`.

In C++, the only difference between a `class` and `struct` is that member visibility in a `class` defaults to `private`, but in a `struct` defaults to `public` (so the `public:` tag isn't accomplishing anything in this case).

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  Silly question (if you'd humor me): In C++, can structs have methods as well? Reword: Obviously structs *can* have methods, but this is a complete surprise for me.  What is the design reason behind this, possibly?

Comment: @Sabuncu: Yes--as stated in the answer, in C++ a `struct` is *exactly* like a `class` except that visibility defaults to `public` instead of `private`. I believe the reasoning was probably pretty simple: to build on an existing concept instead of introducing something new and different for no particular reason.

Comment: Also note that this is a COM interface which implies a rather rigid binary contract (the vtable is the relevant part here). The template method will not add anything to the vtable, so it does not break the contract. It has been added purely as a convenience in this header. The canonical version of IUnknown does not have this fourth method.